# Once image is clicked it will "pop out" compared to other images?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three images, and each image has a value with it, so the first img=1, second img=2, third img=3.

What I can't figure out is how to select one, make the others look transparent and use the value of the image selected?

Is there a way to do it through html5, css3?

Below is an example similar to what I want it to look like when I click (in the example it is based on hover):

http://jsbin.com/umacat/4/edit

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to do something on click you need Javascript.

Comment: It can only be done with JS. You can bind the click event, and store a toggle state (clicked on once vs clicked on twice) for each click. Read the toggle state upon each click event and determine whether to show the image or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my strategy:

1. Store the toggle state, say, `clickToggle`, as a data object in each element.
2. Update the `clickToggle` value when you click on — this value is also checked and allowed to determine the mode of action
3. Perform the necessary actions after evaluating the value of `clickToggle`. Instead of using `:hover`, we will toggle a class to be added/removed.

Here is the updated CSS:

```
.box.toggled {
   box-shadow: 0 2px 8px #334;
   background:#ccd;
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
   transform: scale(1.1);
   opacity:1;
}
```

Here is the code I have, and [demonstrated to be working](http://jsbin.com/umacat/163/edit), too:

```
$(function(){
  $('.box').on('click', function(e) {
    // Prevent default function
    e.preventDefault();

    // Check state
    if(!$(this).data('clickToggle') || $(this).data('clickToggle') === 0) {

      // Update state, add class
      $(this)
      .data('clickToggle', 1)
      .addClass('toggled');

      // Force siblings to revert to original state
      $(this)
      .siblings()
        .data('clickToggle', 0)
        .removeClass('toggled');

    } else if($(this).data('clickToggle') === 1) {

      // Update state, remove class
      $(this)
      .data('clickToggle', 0)
      .removeClass('toggled');
    }
  });
});
```